# How do I calculate regression line using a data set with repeated values indicated as frequencies?

Tags: statistics, regression

I have a data set that comprises of Independent Variable $(X)$ and Dependent Variable $(Y)$ values with a certain frequency $(F)$.
I know that I have to find $x^2$ and $xy$ but how do I factor in the frequency?
I am calculating regression using the least squares method ($Y = a + bX$).
For clarity, this is the data set that I am working with.
`Frequency (F) Independent Variable (X) Dependent Variable (Y)
      3                  4                       60
      4                  4                       65
      2                  5                       65
      4                  5                       70
      3                  6                       75
      2                  6                       80
      4                  7                       85
      3                  8                       90`

Comment: What do you mean by "factor in the frequency"?

Comment: When I calculate b I have to use frequency for the equation but not for any of the other variables. I am not sure whether i should be using the frequency for anything else.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get what you mean by frequency

Comment: If I were to find the mean for example I would use ΣFX/ΣF.

Comment: If your use of frequency is simply to compact the table of values, you could simply expand your dataset to have 25 rows and use whatever regression package you have.  Alternatively, some packages allow for a "weight" variable in which you can identify the frequency.  So...what package are your using?  And having a very small discrete set of dependent variable values suggests that you might have more issues with not meeting the typical error structure assumptions (such as the normality of the residuals).

Comment: Then it is easy: $\sumΧ=(4+4+4)+(4+4+4+4)+(5+5)+(5+5+5+5)+...$. Similarly $\sumΧY=(4\cdot60+4\cdot60+4\cdot60)+(4\cdot65+4\cdot65+4\cdot65+4 \cdot 65)+(5 \cdot 65+5 \cdot 65)+(5\cdot70+5\cdot70+5\cdot70+5\cdot70)+...$

Comment: I got it, thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This dataset is presented in an unusual format that might lead to
confusion in several ways. The Comments show how to do basic
computations that lead to estimating the slope and intercept of the
regression line.

**Obtain true data vectors.** More systematically, here is how such a dataset might be handled
in R statistical software. First, we need to get the 'true' data vectors for $x$ and $y$.

```
 f = c(3,4,2,4,3,2,4,3)
 xx = c(4,4,5,5,6,6,7,8)
 yy = c(60,65,65,70,75,80,85,90)
 x = rep(xx, times=f)   # use frequencies to expand x-vector
 y = rep(yy, times=f)   # use frequencies to expand y-vector
 x; y  # true data vectors
 ## [1] 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 8 8 8
 ## [1] 60 60 60 65 65 65 65 65 65 70 70 70 70 75 75 75 80 80 85 85 85 85
 ## [23] 90 90 90
```

**Find regression line.** Then we do the linear regression. (You might want to use parts of the output, slightly abbreviated here, to check your own computations.)

```
 lm.info = lm(y ~ x);  lm.info
 summary(lm.info)

 ## Call:
 ## lm(formula = y ~ x)

 ## Residuals:
 ##     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
 ## -4.5217 -1.6522  0.4783  1.2174  3.3478 

 ## Coefficients:
 ##             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
 ## (Intercept)   33.870      1.982   17.09 1.45e-14 
 ## x              7.130      0.344   20.73  < 2e-16 

 ## Residual standard error: 2.333 on 23 degrees of freedom
 ## Multiple R-Squared: 0.9492,     Adjusted R-squared: 0.947 
 ## F-statistic: 429.6 on 1 and 23 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

We see that the regression line is $\hat Y = 33.87 + 7.13x,$ 
where $\hat \beta_9 = 33.87$ and $\hat \beta_1 = 7.13$
are both significantly different from $0.$ Moreover, about 95%
of the variability in $y$ is 'explained' by regression on $x.$

**Make informative scatterplot.** Another potential difficulty lies in plotting data with repeated values. The plot on the left shows fewer dots than data points because some of the points are 'overplotted' (dots fall on top of
one another). One might think there are only 8 datapoints.

One cure for this is to 'jitter' the data; that is,
to introduce small random errors that are just big enough to
separate the points, but not big enough to give a misleading impression
of the dataset. The regression line is shown in both plots below. In the jittered plot one
can see that there are more than 8 datapoints (25 actually).

```
 par(mfrow=c(1,2))  # puts two panels per figure
   plot(x, y, pch=20, main="Overplotting")
     abline(coefficients(lm.info))  
   jx = runif(length(x), -.1, .1)  # random jitters for x's
   jy = runif(length(y), -.3, .3)  # random jitters for y's
   plot(x+jx, y+jy, pch=20, main="Jittering")
     abline(coefficients(lm.info))
 par(mfrow=c(1,1))  # returns to default single panel
```

[image]

Note: If you are interested in learning more about using R for regression,
you can find several tutorials by searching the Internet for
`simple linear regression in R`. Many other statistical software
packages provide similar output.